# AC motor control

Tags: motor, ac

I have a simple AC motor, a pump. There is no kind of regulator in terms of speed or pressure. Its supply is 230 Vac, 50 Hz.

If I decide to lower its supply voltage, what happens?

- it will require more current, and will get it as long as the power supply can deliver. That would mean the pump strives to get the power it wants. That does not totally make sense to me, the pump would wind up very fast if not physically loaded (which is ok to do according to its spec).
- it will run slower. That does not make sense to me either, the speed should be controlled by the supply frequency, 50 Hz, right?
- it will not use more current. The power is reduced and the pump will not manage to do its job if things get tough. As long as its an easy job there's no problem, though.

If I want to limit the pressure the pump can deliver, my spontaneous solution would be to limit the available current, but maybe lowering the voltage would be enough?

Comment: Possibly the best solution is to use on/off control with pressostat.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure delivered by your pump is defined by its geometry and the rotation speed (60Hz gives 1800 RPM in 4-pole motors). Reducing the operating voltage will force the motor out of its operating point, make it overheat and ultimately fail. Limiting the current will do the same, only without the overheat&fail part, since stall motor has near-zero resistance and won't dissipate much heat from the current.

Comment: Yes.  Burn out on low voltage is a good possibility.  We lived at the end of the (long) power line in a rural area and the line voltage was low.  The power company should have fixed it but didn't.  We burned out several water pumps in a couple of years.  When the power meter burned out spectacularly in the middle of a Louisiana summer night, the power company replaced the meter and finally fixed the voltage.  Pump motors didn't burn out after that,

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the voltage can reduce the speed of an induction motor to a limited extent. If the motor is driving a centrifugal pump, the reduced speed results in reduced load torque. That would tend to prevent the motor from overheating. Something similar is used to control the speed of ceiling and window fans. However, those motors are designed for that mode of operation. Reducing the voltage of an induction motor that is not designed for that operation will risk overheating.

Limiting current can only be done by limiting the voltage. If the current is limited too much, the motor will stall.

Variable-frequency inverters are often used to control induction motor speed. The inverters are equipped with various features required to provide good variable-speed motor performance and protect the motor. They are usually marketed as variable-frequency drives (VFDs). VFDs work best with 3-phase motors. Very few VFDs are designed for use with single-phase motors. Their use is limited to fans and centrifugal pumps driven by permanent split capacitor (PSC) motors or shaded-pole motors. If you have a single-phase pump, the most economical solution may be to buy a 3-phase motor and a VFD that converts single-phase power to three-phase.

Answer (score 0):

You should not just lower the supply voltage due to the change in current. The change in current will cause the motor to overheat.

If you want to lower the pressure you need to change the revolution speed (< 50 Hz). To do this you will need an inverter.